# Should table names be prefixed with the database name and period when using MySQL/PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The vast majority of queries I've seen have the database name followed by a period before the table name. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase.mytable;
```

However, this seems to work just as well:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

Is there a reason to have the `mydatabase.` before each table name?

I am using MySQL via PDO in PHP.

Comment: I think the documentation answers this, doesn't it?

Comment: @arkascha I don't know. I did some searching, but maybe I'm not using the right terminology or looking in the right places.

Comment: First hit in google for "mysql documentation prefix table with database name": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html That text clearly states the required format any when you need to qualify a table name right after the introduction: "You need not specify a tbl_name or db_name.tbl_name prefix for a column reference in a statement unless the reference would be ambiguous. " Don't get me wrong! Not trying to be an asshole. I just try to point out that reading the documentation _always_ is worth the time.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a reason to have the mydatabase. before each table name

Yes, if you are performing a `cross database query`; where you are actually accessing and joining tables from different database. An example below where `db1` and `db2` are different databases.

```
select t1.*,t2.some_column
from db1.table1 t1  
inner join db2.table2 t2 on t1.some_id_column = t2.some_id_column;
```

But if you are accessing from tables from same database and running the query against that database then no need specifying a fully qualified name (`DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME`)

Answer (score 2):

If you are only ever going to use one database, then there is no need to define it in every query. The only reason to use `mydatabase.mytable` is if you are connecting to multiple databases.